Decrypting a string with private key (RSA 2048 Key size)
I am working with an API that returns sensitive data. This data will need to be decrypted on the client side with the key pair that has been generated by the client.
Below is the JSON Payload that will be sent to the server. This payload is used to encrypt the Sensitive Data. Note: I do not control the of API server.
{
    "exponent": "010001"
    "keyId": 0,
    "identifier": "RSA Key Identifier",
    "appName": "App name",
    "modulus": "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",
}

I do not have any prior knowledge of cryptography, but i researched on how to create a RSA key pair with openssl
Below the Config used to create the RSA key pair
$config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 2048,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);


//Continue to create the key PAIR//
$resource = openssl_pkey_new($config);
openssl_pkey_export($resource, $privateKey);

$pubKeyArr = openssl_pkey_get_details($resource);
$publicKey = $pubKeyArr["key"];

file_put_contents('publicKey',$publicKey);
file_put_contents('privateKey', $privateKey);

Below is a copy of my generated public & private keys respectively.
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuIwf4CRrGzTnYYThKjX8
aMRYIcOZSC7U6/HF9qx5+MEPMx1lsAC8K0G35RMD1KLVpoX68eYGnDCj3dJf69wC
+pdY98vjGm9GQpN1TEQeyKBUVD8V7Fr5SmTaVFBWgllj3hjvogSImDS9quq2XshJ
fuLzTCXHm5MnK67goPitTgE3lZsBh18B1xxjnhbOG4lEceGC8zIqUAKZtTZteYMz
6rXuI+RmLE/YCoLYPryXTFGWkCwzkAPEPKFry/nP34yi1QfpTqwJCb7zTBJ3IzM3
ImteSreX6jHtiWKDU9NiPsNK+viiZ8+Gusxt2gWd7TXXZM5rHrxfMoqdrPjuzrWa
lQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Here are the challenges I faced.

I do not know how to generate the Modulus
I do not know how to come by the Exponent for my keys
I do not know how to generate the identifier for the RSA keys i generated earlier.

Here is what i tried so far.
Response from the API server (Base64 Encoded)
$extendedDetails = '{"ExtendedDetails": {
    "CardNumber": "{base64encryptedString}",
    "ExpiryDate": "{base64encryptedString}",
    "CVV2": "{base64encryptedString}",
    "CardLimits": []
}}';


$cDetails = json_decode($extendedDetails, true);

$pan = base64_decode($cDetails['ExtendedDetails']['CardNumber']);
$exp = base64_decode($cDetails['ExtendedDetails']['ExpiryDate']);
$cv2 = base64_decode($cDetails['ExtendedDetails']['CVV2']);

$decryption_result = openssl_private_decrypt($pan, $decryptedPan, file_get_contents('privateKey'));

var_dump($decryption_result); // Returns bool(false)//
var_dump($decryptedPan); // Empty String//

openssl_private_decrypt returns false, my data is not decrypted.

When base64-decoded, the encrypted contents like CardNumber are all 294 bytes. But your RSA is 2048 bits=256 bytes, so they cannot be RSA-encrypted output if your public key was used. Perhaps you need more details about the API requirements.

What you send as modulus in the payload is not the hex encoding of the modulus but of the public key in SPKI format. If you Base64 encode the value instead of hex, you will receive the body of the public PEM key you have posted. You can determine the modulus with an ASN.1/DER parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk The api documentation stated: Encryption Algorithm: RSA and the Key Size: 2048

@Topaco: That must be it. When hex-decoded, that SPKI value is 294 bytes, so it's using that as the modulus!

@OswaldJenna: Topaco found the problem. Your "modulus" in your JSON payload is not the modulus, is the full public key including the exponent in an encoded form. Just change that to the actual modulus.

actual modulus should be b5366d798333eab5ee23e4662c4fd80a82d83ebc974c5196902c339003c43ca16bcbf9cfdf8ca2d507e94eac0909bef34c1277233337226b5e4ab797ea31ed89628353d3623ec34afaf8a267cf86bacc6dda059ded35d764ce6b1ebc5f328a9dacf8eeceb59a95

This request concerns me, as the payload contains PAN and CVV. Both you and the API host are almost certainly violating PCI DSS, encryption or not. The fact that CVV is even present here is a huge red flag.

As pointed out by Topaco, your modulus field does not contain just the modulus, it contains the entire public key including the exponent, in SubjectPublicKeyInfo (or SPKI) format. To get just the modulus, you need to do something like:
$pem_pub = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuIwf4CRrGzTnYYThKjX8
aMRYIcOZSC7U6/HF9qx5+MEPMx1lsAC8K0G35RMD1KLVpoX68eYGnDCj3dJf69wC
+pdY98vjGm9GQpN1TEQeyKBUVD8V7Fr5SmTaVFBWgllj3hjvogSImDS9quq2XshJ
fuLzTCXHm5MnK67goPitTgE3lZsBh18B1xxjnhbOG4lEceGC8zIqUAKZtTZteYMz
6rXuI+RmLE/YCoLYPryXTFGWkCwzkAPEPKFry/nP34yi1QfpTqwJCb7zTBJ3IzM3
ImteSreX6jHtiWKDU9NiPsNK+viiZ8+Gusxt2gWd7TXXZM5rHrxfMoqdrPjuzrWa
lQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

$rsa_pub = openssl_pkey_get_public($pem_pub);
$pub_key_details = openssl_pkey_get_details($rsa_pub);
$modulus = $pub_key_details["rsa"]["n"];
$modulus_hex = bin2hex($modulus);


@president-james-k-polk Thanks so much. That did it
